# How to import a module for all others modules imported?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have been trying to solve this problem for some hours without any success, I have a PHP background and it will work there but not with python

Let's suppose I have a file named Main.py:

```
import time
import myfunction

myfunction.Calculate()
```

And myfunction.py is something like:

```
def Calculate()
  print('Thank you')
  time.sleep(1)
```

When I run Main.py, it will crash saying 'time is not defined in my function', but it was defined even before importing my_function, why it does not work?

Comment: Each file has its own namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution is to import `time` in your `myfunction.py` file. Import things where they are really used:

**myfunction.py**

```
import time

def Calculate()
  print('Thank you')
  time.sleep(1)
```

**main.py**

```
import myfunction

myfunction.Calculate()
```

Comment: Thank you pretty much, it really works. I have just one last question, how does it even work?. I mean, I am just executing Calculate() function, it is supposed the only code running is the one inside that function, isn't it?